# Numpy: Check for duplicates in first column and keep row with highest value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates

I am having issues to find a numpy way how to filter an array for duplicates (check for duplicates only first value in row)   and then keep only  the row with the highest value (check second values in row for that)

Many thanks

Before

```
np.array([[1,2],
          [2,9],
          [2,8],
          [2,7],
          [1,11],
          [3,6]])
```

After

```
np.array([[2,9],
          [1,11],
          [3,6]])
```

Comment: Does order of the output matter?

Comment: no it doesnt matter

Comment: @Divakar in the duplicate, groups appear to be contiguous. That doesn't seem to be the case here, so your solution would need modification / may not apply here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The accepted solution should work on a generic case as well. I get this with it - `[[ 1, 11],[ 2,  9],[ 3,  6]])`, which seems right.

Comment: @Divakar Okay! Fair enough. Deleting my answer.